# Python - Threading and Json combine

Tags: python, json, multithreading

So currently im trying to get a function right. Basically im trying to do a multiple (Concurrently) thread that takes information from a Json file into the program and then for every thread it should use each json object and then execute the code with those information.

*What I have done so far:*

```
#Read json File
with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    profiles_string = json.load(json_data)

def get_individual_profiles(config):
    top_layer = config.get('Profiles')
    if top_layer:
        top_level_keys = ['profile_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(top_layer))]
        print(top_level_keys)
        return [(key, top_layer.get(key)) for key in top_level_keys]
    return []

def stringify(key, next_layer):
    return [
        ' '.join(key.capitalize().split('_')),
        next_layer.get('Name'),
        next_layer.get('Last_Name'),
        next_layer.get('Email'),
        next_layer.get('Phone')
        #etc etc...
        ]

    config = profiles_string
profiles = get_individual_profiles(config)

print('one at a time:')
for item in profiles:
    print(stringify(*item))

pool = ThreadPool()

# Launch a process for each item
threads = [pool.apply_async(stringify, tuple(item)) for item in profiles]


# get() the results as each finishes
results = [res.get() for res in threads]
print('threaded results:')
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
threaded results:
['Profile 0', 'Thrill', 'Ofit', 'Stack@hotmail.com', '123 412 123']

['Profile 1', 'Hellow', 'World', 'Stac321k@hotmail.com', '543 412 312']
```

Which is great. But the **issues is:**

That whenever I want to etc use those info

**EXEMPLE**

```
def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):
payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
              "Name": item["Name"],
                "Last_Name": item["Last_Name"],
                "Email": item["Email"],
                  "Phone": item["Phone"],
```

Is that it wont recognize those attributes but what I need to do is that I need to call them by item[1].. item[2] etc from that order that is from `def stringify(key, next_layer):` which I don't know by now how to make it so I don't need to do it.

The other problem is that whenever we say ETC that I use item[1] in the code. Then it will only use the last thread and skip the rest. So if I do

```
print(item[1])
```

Then the only output that will come is the last one which is *Hello*

So the problems I need to get solved:

1. To make each thread to execute concurrently and execute the code with those information
2. Make a fix so I don't need to use item[1] but to use instead item['Name'].

Any ideas!? :)

**EDIT**

Json file

```
      {
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "Color": "Red",
            "house_number": "123",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
            "My-Note": "aasfase",
            "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "5634543",
            "postal_code": "123445",
            "given_name": "Balling",
            "Last_name": "Calling",
            "street_address": "qwertr 123",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "phone": "65412331",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "house_number": "321",
            "year": "2018"
        }

        #Profile_2 etc etc
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

NameUrl = config["Url"]

myNote = config["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                  "given_name": config["Name"],
                "Last_name": config["LastName"],

                "street_address": config["Address"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "city": config["City"],
                "country": config["Country"],
                "email": config["Email"],
                "phone": config["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config["Color"],
            "house_number": config["houseNumber"],
            "year": config["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

Comment: Threads cannot execute concurrently in a proper sense because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) meaning that only 1 thread is ever executing code at any one time. Are you hoping for speed through Threads?  You might be able to use multiprocessing

Comment: Well I was more thinking like we can say etc we have 50 profiles. Execute them all. My code is not that heavy so it shouldn't take a good amout of time/speed. I guess, What do you suggest @roganjosh

Comment: Then I would suggest avoiding multiprocessing or multithreading, for something this size they overcomplicate the code and probably slow it down. Just process the json response as normal.

Comment: Oh okey. But in that case how would I do that? I think I have the code pretty much well. Currently I know how to process the json response as normal (Only for 1 profile)

Comment: Maybe `results = [stringify(item) for item in profiles]`?

Comment: Im gonna edit now the code abit and show you how the code would work with only 1 profile. Be here in 2 minutes!

Comment: There we go! So basically I have that json file and that code. That would work absolutly fine. But what if I have more profiles/objects?

Comment: That's not valid json. What is the repeating unit?

Comment: There we go! I by accident removed alot of the codes. Just updated it!

Comment: Pretty much what it does now is that if I just one profile then all the information from Json will be added into the program etc what we can see in ```Challange```. All that will be added but whenever I start to use another profile then it will not understand that there is two profiles of course.

Comment: Ok, I _think_ I know your issue but it might be a while before I'm back at a computer. I will try answer tonight if it's not answered by someone else. Basically it looks like you expected threads to do the job of `dict.items()`

Comment: Probably. Is there a way I can get a contact with you incase you maybe forget or so :) ? Would really appreciate your help in any ways! Been stuck for days

Comment: By the way. I added in the first code both for profile by profile and with multiprocessing. I think there should be a way to use multiprocess but I think its a dict.items issue that is the hint at this moment because the thread is there and it does give me the correct Json answers. So yeah. I hope you understand ish what I mean!

Comment: @roganjosh You there :)?